# Como comprimir os meus ficheiros dos Resources

Tags: c#, arquivo, compressão-de-imagem, compressão

Estou a desenvolver um jogo de Batalha-Naval (ainda sou principiante em programação) e estou a adicionar algumas músicas e imagens.

O meu problema é que isto está a aumentar demasiado o tamanho do projecto/jogo e atrapalha.

Há alguma forma de comprimir os ficheiros todos para um ficheiro e ainda assim poder aceder aos mesmos a partir do código?

Por exemplo, os recursos que tenho em `Resources` eu uso:

```
Properties.Resources.exemplo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma possível sugestão é que você implemente uma [Custom Resource Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) que funcione como um *broker* entre os seus arquivos marcados como `Resources` e os pontos da sua aplicação que consomem estes recursos.

Esta classe seria responsável por descompactar os recursos antes de passá-los ao resto da aplicação.